# Implementing a back button (in CDF)

Tags: programming, button

I have a rather large notebook, which contains a lot of hyperlinks to different parts of the notebook.

Is it possible to make a back button (maybe as a docked cell button?) so that when a reader clicks a link and is moved up or down in the document, then he can click the button and then return to the location of the link?

Comment: This sounds possible, but you'll get faster and better responses it you "seed" the discussion with some examples you've tried.

Comment: The Mac version of Mathematica has a back button in the toolbar.

Comment: The Help notebook toolbar also has back (and forward) buttons.  You can see the code for this toolbar by executing `FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]` and the `ButtonFunction` for the back button is `FrontEndToken[FrontEnd\`ButtonNotebook[], "HyperlinkGoBack"]`.

Comment: @Mike Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

A simple back button can be implemented using

```
Button["Back", FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[],
 "HyperlinkGoBack"], Evaluator -> None]
```

The `Evaluator -> None` option ensures that this is processed by the Front End.

I'll leave it to the OP to work out how to turn this into a docked cell (if they haven't already done so some time ago!).

For a more sophisticated button, this is a modification of the help toolbar code I mentioned in my comment to the OP:

```
Tooltip[DynamicModule[{$CellContext`destination$$ = 0}, 
      Dynamic[If[FEPrivate`HistoryList["Back"] === {}, 
        Button[Import[
          FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",
             "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Toolbars", "DocCenter", 
            "DisabledBackIcon.png"}]], Enabled -> False, 
         Appearance -> None, FrameMargins -> 0], 
        Button[PaneSelector[{True -> 
            Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
               "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Toolbars", 
               "DocCenter", "BackIconHot.png"}]], 
           False -> 
            Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
           "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Toolbars", 
           "DocCenter", "BackIcon.png"}]]}, 
      Dynamic[CurrentValue["MouseOver"]]], 
     FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[], "HyperlinkGoBack"], 
     Evaluator -> None, Appearance -> None, FrameMargins -> 0]]], 
  DynamicModuleValues :> {}], "Go back"]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Was your prompt part of a general purge of unanswered questions?

Comment: It's me who is doing the slaughter. Relaxing thing when I'm bored :p

Answer (score 0):

If you put the button in a normal cell of the same notebook, you gain nothing because you can't easily access the button, so you must put the button in a palette or dock cell.

To make it simple, I have created a palette:

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["Back",
  FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "HyperlinkGoBack"], 
   Evaluator -> None], 
 Magnification -> 2]
```

then saved and installed as explained in [Creating Palettes, Wolfram technical note](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html)

Now when I need to go back from internal hyperlink, I open the palette and click the Back button.